# Excel RANK function is not working

Tags: excel

This is the excel sheet.

```
| - | A  |           B           |
| 1 | 10 | =RANK(A1,$A$1:$A$4)=1 |
| 2 | 8  | =RANK(A2,$A$1:$A$4)=2 |
| 3 | 8  | =RANK(A3,$A$1:$A$4)=2 |
| 4 | 7  | =RANK(A4,$A$1:$A$4)=4 |
```

What can I do to return 3 in B4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($A$1:$A$4>A1,(1/COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,$A$1:$A$4,$A$1:$A$4,">" & A1))))+1
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer. @TarequeMdHanif

Answer (score 0):

If your list is always going to be ordered, then

B1 =1
B2 =if(A2=A1,B1,B1+1)

Autofill B2 down so

B3 =if(A3=A2,B2,B2+1)

etc